# How can I get the current git commit sha inside a Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, aws-cloudformation

I'm running a Cloudformation template inside a github action, and I'd like to reference the current git commit sha/id.

The above example is an output but my end goal is to use the commit sha to read the correct version of code from AWS S3 for deploying a lambda, so any other thoughts on how to do that are welcome.

I've googled everywhere but I can't find the syntax, ideally something like this:

```
"Outputs": {
      "CommitSHA": {
         "Value": { "Fn::Sub": "${{ github.sha }}" }
      },
```

Comment: How are you deploying that CF template? You should either create it dynamically with the current sha literally as part of the template or have it as a parameter of the CF template and pass in the right value. Obviously CF itself does not know anything / care about git(hub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems be less about CloudFormation and more about how Github Actions work. But nonetheless, I can still help you out.

There are 3 things we need here:

1. Figure out how to get the commit hash within a GitHub action

Within your Github workflow you can use the below variable to obtain the hash. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/commit-hash#inputs

> ${{github.sha}}

2. Add parameters to your CloudFormation template so that it can accept this commit hash.

```html
Parameters:
  GithubHash:
    Type: String
```

3. Output the inputted GitHub hash within your CloudFormation template.

```html
"Outputs" : {
  "GithubHash" : {
    "Description": "The Github Hash",  
    "Value" : { "Ref" : "GithubHash" }
  }
}
```

Comment: you're right, I think I didn't know what I didn't know here! thanks for the response